# $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k\mod n$ where $n=p^a$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My friend said that for any $n=p^a$, where $p$ is **odd prime**, $a$ is positive integer then: If $k$ is divisible by $p-1$ then $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k\equiv -p^{a-1}\pmod{p^a}$.  I am very sure that his result is wrong. My though is simple: I use primitive root of $p^a$. But I fail to construct a counterexample for him. So my question is that: Could we construct an example of  $k$ so that $p-1\mid k$ and $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k\not\equiv -p^{a-1}\pmod{p^a}$.

The second question is that: Does the following holds:  $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k\not\equiv -p^{a-1}\pmod{p^a}$ if and only if $p-1\mid k$?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197469/value-of-sum-i-1p-ik-pmodp

Answer (score 1):

$n=4$, $p=2$, $a=2$, $k=3$, $1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3\equiv0\pmod4$ would seem to be a counterexample to your friend's statement.

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry that I fogot $p$ is odd prime.