# $1^n+2^n+...+(p-1)^n$ is divisible by $p$ for $p> n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility, exponentiation

The Problem is to prove that $p|1^n+...+(p-1)^n$ for $p>n+1$,
$p$ is a prime.

For $n$ being odd it is pretty straight forward.
For $n$ being even, I am not able to solve it, thinking some connection
with orders or primitive root(the handout is on these topics) because of $n\leq p-2$

**How is this question different?**

This was termed a duplicate of this [$1^n +2^n + \cdots +(p-1)^n \mod p =$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511444/1n-2n-cdots-p-1n-mod-p)

I am not able to follow from the hints and want a better hint/solution for this question.

It also has an additional condition.